# ASP.Net MVC5 and StructureMap4 - Simplified Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap4

While integrating [StructureMap.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC5/) to an ASP.Net MVC5 web application, realized that it uses 3.1 version of SM and not 4+. Then tried taking the files included in this Nuget and changing it for SM4, but a lot of code was there and several incompatible calls across SM3.1 and SM4.

With that, I ended up writing a simple IoC as below. Looking for advise on its shortfalls and what inefficiencies this have compared to the Nuget version linked here.

**Define Default Registry**

```
public class DefaultRegistry : Registry
{
    public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.Assembly("MyAssembly");
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });

        For<IContext<SomeClass>>().Use<MyContext>();
    }
}
```

**Create a Static Container**

```
public static class IoC {
    private static IContainer container = new Container(c => c.AddRegistry<DefaultRegistry>());
    public static IContainer Container { get { return container; } }
}
```

**Override the Controller Factory**

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)IoC.Container.GetInstance(controllerType);
    }
}
```

**Register in Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
}
```

This works, but worried that am over-simplifying it and this might introduce other issues. Looking for insights into problems with this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two things. You need this in the DefaultRegistry to have a more robust registration of Controllers:

```
scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
```

Here is the ControllerConvention for StructureMap 4:

```
public class ControllerConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void ScanTypes(TypeSet types, Registry registry)
    {
        foreach (var type in types.AllTypes().Where(type => type.CanBeCastTo<Controller>() && !type.IsAbstract))
        {
            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle());
        }
    }
}
```

Second, using the `DependencyResolver` is preferable over creating your own `DefaultControllerFactory`. MVC's implementation is richer as you can see [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs). You could copy that to your own but that's not future proof and most of all, not needed because you can just use `DependencyResolver`, keeping your code simpler. Basically, use the classes `StructuremapMvc`and `StructureMapDependencyScope` you get from installing StructureMap.MVC5. You could move the initialization and disposing from `StructuremapMvc` to the Global.asax if you prefer.

```
public static StructureMapDependencyScope StructureMapDependencyScope { get; set; }

public static void End()
{
    StructureMapDependencyScope.Dispose();
}

public static void Start()
{
    IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
    StructureMapDependencyScope = new StructureMapDependencyScope(container);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(StructureMapDependencyScope);
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(StructureMapScopeModule));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the note on ControllerConvention. Will use that.

Please add some details around why it is better to stick to `DependencyResolver`. If it is some edge case or micro-optimization, I would prefer to skip in the interest of keeping things simple.

Comment: In short, MVC's implementation of `GetControllerInstance` is more complete and while you could copy that implementation to your own, it would be bad practice. I updated the answer with this as well, including a link to the MVC implementation